# display all films in a database haskell

Tags: haskell

```
    -- Types
    type Title = String

type Actor = String
type Cast = [Actor]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]
type Period = (Year, Year)
type Database = [Film]



 testDatabase :: Database
testDatabase = [("The Gunman", ["Idris Elba", "Sean Penn", " Javier Bardem"], 
               2015,["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),("The Shawshank Redemption", ["Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman", "Bob Gunton"],1994, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry"]),
                ("The Dark Knight", ["Christian Bale", "Heath Ledger","Aaron Eckhart"], 2008, ["Zoe","Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"]),
                ("Inception", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Ellen Page"], 2010, ["Jo", "Emma", "Zack", "Olga", "Kevin"])]


displayAllFilms :: Database ->[(Title, Cast, Year, Fans)]
displayAllFilms [] = []
displayAllFilms ((i, j, k, l): xs)
    |l == [] = (i, j, k, []) : displayAllFilms xs
    |otherwise = (i, j, k, l) : displayAllFilms xs
```

And i get this error> I dont know what to do. What is the Error?

```
*Main> displayAllFilms

<interactive>:13:1:
    No instance for (Show (Database -> [(Title, Cast, Year, Fans)]))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Show (Database -> [(Title, Cast, Year, Fans)]))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: I don't know why this question is getting such a negative reception. It strikes me as quite unexceptional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the error message; ghci tells you that you're trying to print a function of type *Database -> [(Title, Cast, Year, Fans)]* and that it doesn't know how to do that.

Presumably, you tried printing `displayAllFilms`, whereas you probably meant `displayAllFilms testDatabase`